# What is .new()?

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, nodejs, truffle-deployment

I am using the following code to deploying a smart contract to a private network with Node-js. But the error `TypeError: contract_object.new is not a function` occurs. What are `.new()` and the error's solution?

app.js:

```
var Web3=require('web3');
var fs=require('fs');
var solc=require('solc');
var web3=new Web3('ws://127.0.0.1:8545');
var address="0xB6EB958b199219Abf33462d6B348C9709C8E24f8";
var contract_sol=fs.readFileSync('E:/Deploy/contracts/Deploy.sol','utf8');
var contract_compiled=solc.compile(contract_sol);
var contract_json="E:/Deploy/build/contracts/Deploy.json";
var contract_js=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(contract_json));
var contract_abi=contract_js.abi;
var contract_byteCode="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";
var gasEstimate=web3.eth.estimateGas({data:contract_byteCode});
var contract_object=new web3.eth.Contract(contract_abi);
    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(address,"Alireza");
var theContract=contract_object.new({ from: address, data:contract_byteCode, gas: gasEstimate+10000})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some methods to deploy smart contract. But, there is one method that can be applied just in Truffle project. `contract_object.new(…)` command remind that same method that is applicable just in Truffle project. But, the below command:

```
contract_object=new web3.eth.Contract(…)
```

Is applicable using web3 library and even in non-Truffle projects, such that to deploy the contract the command should be used is `contract_object.deploy().send({…});`,  not `contract_object.new(…)`.

Because “truffle-contract” module was not applied in the question code, Just replace the last command with the below:

```
contract_object.deploy().send({ from: address, data:contract_byteCode, gas: gasEstimate+10000});
```

Answer (score 1):

You required `web3` module but used a method of `truffle-contract` module while you didn't require it. So, you just can use all methods that `web3` provides to you. The command:

```
var theContract=contract_object.new({ from: address, data:contract_byteCode, gas: gasEstimate+10000})
```

uses `truffle-contract` module's method. Just replace that with the below command that is a `web3` module's command:

```
contract_object.deploy().send({ from: <address>, data:contract_byteCode, gas: gasEstimate+10000});
```

Answer (score 0):

`new web3.eth.Contract` calls the constructor of class `web3.eth.Contract`.

This constructor (naturally) returns an instance of class `web3.eth.Contract`.

Your attempt:

```
var contract_object=new web3.eth.Contract(...);
var theContract=contract_object.new(...);
```

Fails because class `web3.eth.Contract` does not have a member function named `new`.

You are most likely confusing it with Truffle's `artifacts.require('<ContractName>').new`.

Comment: Do you mean i use `var theContract=artifacts.require(contract_object).new(...)` instead of `var theContract=contract_object.new(...);` or another code is needed?

Comment: @A.Kiakojouri: Read the answer. It says `artifacts.require('<ContractName>').new(...)`. And it will only work within a Truffle environment (e.g., when you execute `truffle test` from a command line).